# In search of book(s) by the Koznitser Maggid

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism, maharal

I'm in search of a possibility to read online (and free) some books of [Rabbi Yisroel Hopsztajn Hupstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisroel_Hopsztajn#Books), most specifically the work *Geulath Israel* (on the writings of the Maharal). He cited this book a lot in his *Avodath Israel*, but I don't find the actual book anywhere. Does anyone know of this book?

Comment: I assume you mean: גאולת ישראל - הגהות וביאורים על ספרי המהר"ל מפראג, גבורות ה', נר מצווה ובאר הגולה‏ - וארשא, שנת הכת”ר [תרכ”ה] 1865. מהדורה ראשונה.

Comment: @Loewian Exactly

Comment: I guess [first 40 pages for free](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?102919&&lang=eng) doesn't count, but in case you missed it.

Comment: @Cauthon
80% is good.
I will begin whit this.

Comment: I think the commentary labelled 'Gevurot Hashem' in this hagadah  http://www.hebrewbooks.org/10921 is actually not the Maharal's work but the Kozhnitzer's commentary on it (though maybe chopped-up and re-arranged to make it into a running commentary on the text of the hagadah).

Comment: @paquda See [this](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/14197), an old edition of Maharal. On Beer Hagola they added in appendix some passages.